# How come these 2 lines of code are causing a memory leak?

Tags: c++

I'm confused, I commented these 2 lines out resulting in no memory leaks, and when I added them again it's leaking.

However I can't understand why it's actually leaking?

---

This is the 2 lines of code one of them or both are leaking :

```
m_surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(m_font, m_text.c_str(), m_color_fg);
m_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, m_surface);
```

And here is the declaration of the 2 variables :

```
SDL_Surface* m_surface = nullptr;
SDL_Texture* m_texture = nullptr;
```

---

## I'm not sure what else is needed to figure out why it's leaking.

Comment: They both allocate some kind of memory, probably. If you don't do whatever the API requires you do to do clean up that memory, you'll leak it. So make sure you call the appropriate cleanup routines, and you call them in pairs (so that each 'create' is eventually matched with a 'destroy' or similar).

Comment: Both of these methods create surfaces. The documentation examples suggest you should use `SDL_FreeSurface` to free them.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt But how do I access the surfaces that they create?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://www.google.ca/search?q=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface).

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt In the example they use SDL_FreeSurface() after, which I tried like this : SDL_FreeSurface(m_surface); after the texture was made form the surface.

Comment: Yes; you do this when you no longer need the surface, typically when you close your application, or unload a level or something like that.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt So that is not what causes the leak?

Comment: I can't tell from what I know of your situation.

Comment: I've told you several times that you don't need the member surface, you can replace it with a local variable that you can release safely after you are done with it. Are you releasing the surface correctly? Are you destroying the texture correctly? Oh and the answer to your question: Because you allocate more memory without freeing it.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I'm not using a local variable because I get a error somewhere else in my code when I do, and I thought I needed the texture to be allocated at all times. If not that's probably the problem.

Comment: @BiiX Forget about memory leaks... You will realize what it truly is yourself after you learn a few other things.

Comment: You're currently showing us that `myPtr = new MyPtr();` leaks. We can't guess what you have forgotten to delete, but remember also that we are not here to fix your code for you. I and many others have given you tips on this post and your post about the font texture reloading. All those should be plenty to get you started on fixing the problem. As I said before, feel free to stop by the chat room to see if me or someone else is available to help you.